# Convert date string into DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How to get DateTime from string: (I don't know what format it is)

```
Wed Jan 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

To DateTime?

Comment: -1 because not a lot of effort has gone in to finding an answer prior to posting on SO

Comment: StackOverflow has a wonderful feature: Search. Use it!

Comment: @Dineshkumar I rolled back your changes. Please don't edit "Possible duplicate" into the body of a post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) to parse the string into `DateTime` Object.

You can pass the format according to which you want parsing. Like in your case you would use

```
string dateString = "Wed Jan 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100";
dateString = dateString.Replace("GMT+0100", "+01:00");  // to remove the timezone abbreviation and replace with offset value.

string format = "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what format it is, then how can you expect to parse it? How will you know if the date 2014-01-02 means the 1st Feb or 2nd Jan?

You could use a number of TryParseExact, just to rule out dates it definitely couldn't be (2014-13-12 can only be 13th Dec) but you're still left with those strings that could be parsed and are valid for two dates.